Where to put adverbs in sentences
Adverbs are tricky for example "I go often there" is simple wrong. I need to put an adverb before the verb. It is different with "to be". Here both "he is always on time and he always is on time" are correct, just the other version is more emphatic.
My question is: what if it isn't a simple form of "be" but a negative. Is it still possible to say "he always isn't on time" or this time only "he isn't always on time" is correct?

But "He speaks softly there" is correct, and so is "I go there often".

@TimR that's right but "I go often there" is wrong but "I go often" where often is at the end is correct, right?

Do you go to the race track?  -- I go often.    Yes, that is idiomatic. As is "I go often to the race track" but not "I go often there".

They mean different things.
Google defines always as

at all times; on all occasions

A negation like isn't to always means  not at all times, not on all occasions.  Hence

he isn't always on time

means he's only sometimes on time.

he always isn't on time

means he's late at all times,
on all occasions.

But that's only possible with "be". "He buys always frut" is simply wrong and has to be "he alwats buys fruit"?
